# Order By in Row_number not working properly

Tags: sql, function, row-number

I have `ROW_NUMBER` function that I am using to get the latest record but the `Order by` in the function is not seem to be working. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID, DepartmentID ORDER BY PayDate, WorkDate desc) AS CurrentFlag
FROM test
```

Example of result table:

```
EmployeeID | DepartmentID | Balance | PayDate  |  WorkDate   | CurrentFlag
123          1              200       1/3/2017    12/22/2016   1
123          1              300       1/3/2017    12/23/2016   2
123          1              500       1/5/2017    12/24/2016   3
```

What I should be getting:

```
EmployeeID | DepartmentID | Balance | PayDate  |  WorkDate   | CurrentFlag
123          1              200       1/3/2017    12/22/2016   3
123          1              300       1/3/2017    12/23/2016   2
123          1              500       1/5/2017    12/24/2016   1
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in my `ROW_NUMBER` function. I am ordering it by `PayDate` then `WorkDate` in descending order so I should get `CurrentFlag = 1` for the latest `WorkDate` which is `12/24/2016`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `ORDER BY` item is handled separately, and they are considering `ASC` unless told otherwise.

It appears you want both items to be `DESC`, so try:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID, DepartmentID 
                  ORDER BY PayDate desc, WorkDate desc)
```

Comment: omg thank you so much, i didn't know you have to specify the order for each column

Comment: @Stephanie Hey no problem, happy coding :)